# Kotlin Webflux reactor client retry

Tags: kotlin, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to implement a retry extension function for my webclient where it's not a 200 - I know this is a bad design, but this is just an example. I have this:

Client.class

```
suspend fun getAccountInfo(accountId: String): Account {
    return webclient.get()
            .uri("/accounts/${accountId}")
            .awaitExchange {
                if (it.statusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
                    return@awaitExchange it.awaitBody<Account>()
                } else { //anything not 200
                    return@awaitExchange it.retryIf<Account>(times = 1)
                }
            }
}
```

Extension function - I modeled this from the awaitBody() function from the org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client class.

```
suspend inline fun <reified T : Any> ClientResponse.retryIf(times: Long): T =
    bodyToMono(object : ParameterizedTypeReference<T>() {}).retry(times).awaitSingle()
```

Similar to the awaitBody() method where it works with the bodyToMono(), I'm trying to reference the retry() within the reactor.core.publisher class and add a awaitSingle() at the end.

After running a few tests, I'm seeing:

```
NoSuchElementException: No value received via onNext for awaitSingle
```

Am I missing something to get the webclient to retry?

A quick note:

- An alternative that I saw was to use Kotlin's kotlinx.coroutines.flow class retry(), where I'd pass in the method of calling the client but I want retries on TIMEOUTS/server exceptions to be handled with the client class making the API request.